# How to display a pop up view after a circular rotation of UIImage in Xcode, Swift3?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to make a spin wheel on click of a button. I have made a circular image rotate on button click and it stops after one rotation. Now I want to display a pop up which shows how much points he got . I plan to do that using label. But I am confused on how to show a pop up.

Comment: use alertViewcontroller https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UIAlertViewController

following is swift 3 code

```
var alert = UIAlertController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.alert = UIAlertController(title: "Congratulations!", message: "You have won 100 points", preferredStyle: .alert)
    self.alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: {action in
        switch action.style {
        case .default:
            //do your other stuff ahead after receiving points
        case .cancel:
            print("cancel")
        case .destructive:
            print("destruct")
        }}))
}

//your rotation stopped
//call the UIAlertViewController
self.present(self.alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```